# Proof of the Lévy–Itō decomposition in this paper

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

Let

- $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space;
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space;
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$;
- $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $E$-valued càdlàg $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$-Lévy process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$;
- $$\pi_t(B):=\sum_{\substack{s\in[0,\:t]\\\Delta X_s\ne0}}1_B\left(\Delta X_s(\omega)\right)=\left|\left\{s\in(0,t]:0\ne\Delta X_s\in B\right\}\right|$$ for $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ and $t\ge0$;
- $\lambda(B):=\operatorname E\left[\pi_1(B)\right]$ for $B\in\mathcal B(E)$.

If $B\in\mathcal B(E)$, then $$X^B_t:=\int_Bx\:{\rm d}\pi_t\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ and $X-X^B$ are independent $\mathcal F$-Lévy processes. $X^B_t$ has a compound Poisson distribution with intensity measure $t\left.\lambda\right|_B$.

> I would like to show that $$\lambda(B_1(0)^c)<\infty\tag1$$ and $$\int_{\overline B_1(0)\setminus\{0\}}\|x\|_E^2\:\lambda({\rm d}x)<\infty\tag2.$$

$(2)$ is proven in the proof of [Corollary 9.10-(c) in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.00251.pdf#page=62), but I don't understand the argument. Assuming $E=\mathbb R^d$ for some $d\in\mathbb N$, letting $$U_\delta:=\overline B_1(0)\setminus\overline B_\delta(0)=\left\{x\in\mathbb R^d:\delta<\|x\|\le 1\right\}$$ for $\delta>0$ and denoting the characteric function of a random variable $Z$ by $\varphi_Z$, they show that \begin{equation}\begin{split}0&<\left|\varphi_{X_t}(y)\right|=\left|\varphi_{X^{U_\delta}_t}(y)\right|\\&\le\exp\left(\int_{U_\delta}\cos\langle x,y\rangle-1\:\lambda({\rm d}x)\right)\\&\le\exp\left(-t\int_{U_\delta}\frac{\left|\langle x,y\rangle\right|^2}4\:\lambda({\rm d}x\right)\end{split}\tag3\end{equation} for all $y\in\mathbb R^d$ and $\delta>0$.

> While $(3)$ is certainly correct, I don't get how we obtain $(2)$ from $(3)$ by letting $\delta\to0+$. And how do we show $(1)$?

I guess the argument is supposed to be that the left-hand side of $(3)$ would be $0$, if the integral on the right-hand side is not finite. However, since we let $\delta\to0+$, this limit could still vanish.